# How to use a cookie as a property with ASP.Net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, properties

I am trying to use a property in the back end of a page to set a cookie, I am getting strange results, not sure if what I am doing is the correct way to use cookies.

Anyway my code is below, if you have any ideas on how best to handle this or an example where it has been done already I would be grateful for a response 
Thanks.

```
    int CurrentID
    {
        get
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["CurrentID"] == null)
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CurrentID", "0"));
            return Request.Cookies["CurrentID"].Value.AsID();
        }
        set
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["CurrentID"] != null)
                Response.Cookies.Remove("CurrentID");
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CurrentID", value.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of "strange results"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out when removing then adding a cookie to Responce it does not remove from Reequest and so adds a new cookie with the same name, so when getting the property it got the first version of the cookie which was an old value.

Anyway the solution is as follows.

```
    int CurrentID
    {
        get
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["CurrentID"] != null)
            {
                return Request.Cookies["CurrentID"].Value.AsID();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CurrentID", "0"));
                return 0;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (Response.Cookies["CurrentID"] != null)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Remove("CurrentID");
                Request.Cookies.Remove("CurrentID");
            }
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CurrentID", value.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the getter, you're returning the cookie in the request, but you're not setting it in the request in the case where it doesn't exist.

Perhaps try:

```
if (Request.Cookies["CurrentID"] == null)
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CurrentID", "0"));
    return 0;
}
return Request.Cookies["CurrentID"].Value.AsID();
```

Comment: Cheers for the advice I've taken into consideration what you mentioned and realised that in the Request.Cookies a new cookie was being added every time the property was set and so it contained many cookies with the same name, this caused confusion and ended up with strange results. Anyway got the answer now. Thanks for your help