# Cookies as a property in asp.net (vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

Thanks in advance for looking at my post.  I'm new to cookies.  I figured they'd be easier to work with if I create a property for each key of the collection.  I created a set of private properties to deal with getting/setting cookies so I keep control state between pages.  Here's what I have:

```
Private Property CK_Settings(pKey As String) As String
    Set(value As String)
        If Request.Cookies("Settings") Is Nothing Then
            Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("Settings"))
        End If

        Response.Cookies("Settings").Item(pKey) = value
    End Set
    Get
        If Request.Cookies("Settings") Is Nothing Then
            Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("Settings"))
        End If

        Return Request.Cookies("Settings").Item(pKey)
    End Get
End Property

Private Property CK_rb1 As String
    Set(value As String)
        CK_Settings("rb1") = value
    End Set
    Get
        If CK_Settings("rb1") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return CK_Settings("rb1")
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
End Property

Private Property CK_Jobs As String
    Set(value As String)
        CK_Settings("Jobs") = value
    End Set
    Get
        If CK_Settings("Jobs") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return CK_Settings("Jobs")
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
End Property

Private Property CK_rb2 As String
    Set(value As String)
        CK_Settings("rb2") = value
    End Set
    Get
        If CK_Settings("rb2") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return CK_Settings("rb2")
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub SetCookies()
    Me.CK_rb1 = Me.rb1.SelectedIndex.ToString
    Me.CK_Jobs = Me.ddlJobs.SelectedIndex.ToString
    Me.CK_rb2 = Me.rb2.SelectedIndex.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub GetCookies()
    If Me.CK_rb1 IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.rb1.SelectedIndex = Me.CK_rb1.ToInteger
    End If
    If Me.CK_rb2 IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.rb2.SelectedIndex = Me.CK_rb2.ToInteger
    End If
    Me.ddlJobs.SelectedIndex = Me.CK_Jobs.ToInteger
End Sub
```

I get no compiler/runtime errors, but the cookies aren't being set at all.  I've also added 2 subs for easier setting/getting.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8607777/5317039) when researching online, but I don't think it's relevant.  ANY help at all is GREATLY appreciated!

UPDATE

I was able to get the radiobuttonlist (rb) to retain state.  I'm having issues with the dropdownlist (ddl) retaining state.  It's worth noting that the dropdownlist is a custom control.  Also, I changed the names to something less of consequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdownlist implemented overridden method that I was accounting for.  As soon as I figured this out, I was able to get the ddl to retain state.